# Am I missing something with my image navigation? It's not clickable

Tags: html, image, navigation, pixel

Can someone please help me with the below? My image is not clickable but I'm not sure why?

```
<img src= "makeup.html.jpg" alt= "Make up by Lauren Evans logo" title= "Make up by Lauren Evans"
 width= "300" height= "300" class= "floattoright" usemap= "MakeupbyLaurenEvans" />

 <map name= "Make up by Lauren Evans">
    <area shape= "rect" coords= "0, 0, 230, 218" href= "https://www.instagram.com/makeupbylaurenevans/?hl=en" 
     alt="Make up by Lauren Evans Instagram" />
 </map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code:

```html
<img src= "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653853504933-1241ec829d7c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80" alt= "Make up by Lauren Evans logo" title= "Make up by Lauren Evans"
 width= "300" height= "300" class= "floattoright" usemap= "#MakeupbyLaurenEvans" />

 <map name= "MakeupbyLaurenEvans">
    <area shape= "rect" coords= "0, 0, 230, 218" href= "https://www.instagram.com/makeupbylaurenevans/?hl=en" 
     alt="Make up by Lauren Evans Instagram" />
 </map>
```

Comment: That's great thank you so much! It's now clickable however it doesn't float to right?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's clickable, but you have no `onclick` event to handle it and the `cursor: pointer;` styling is also missing. I have added the styling and some dummy click handler.

```css
img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.nwmgroups.hu/s/img/i/2205/20220525huha-jel1.jpg?w=1280&h=720&t=4" alt= "Make up by Lauren Evans logo" title= "Make up by Lauren Evans"
 width= "300" height= "300" class= "floattoright" usemap= "MakeupbyLaurenEvans" onclick="alert('I was clicked')" />

 <map name= "Make up by Lauren Evans">
    <area shape= "rect" coords= "0, 0, 230, 218" href= "https://www.instagram.com/makeupbylaurenevans/?hl=en" 
     alt="Make up by Lauren Evans Instagram" />
 </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is issue is the code. As you can see from this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_images_map2).

In `usemap` attributes you need to add map tag name with `#` like `usemap= "#MakeupbyLaurenEvans"`. Then in the `map` tag, name should be same as you defined in `usemap` attribute like this:

`name= "MakeupbyLaurenEvans"`

Now, the code looks like this:

```
<img src= "makeup.html.jpg" alt= "Make up by Lauren Evans logo" title= "Make up by Lauren Evans"
 width= "300" height= "300" class= "floattoright" usemap= "#MakeupbyLaurenEvans" />

 <map name= "MakeupbyLaurenEvans">
    <area shape= "rect" coords= "0, 0, 230, 218" href= "https://www.instagram.com/makeupbylaurenevans/?hl=en" 
     alt="Make up by Lauren Evans Instagram" />
 </map>
```

Working [Example](https://codepen.io/musama125/pen/dydmPpE)